# Expressing a joint distribution for use in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have

$$X_1=T + W$$ 
$$X_2=2 T + 3 W$$

where

$$W \sim N(3,5) \,\text{;}\,\, T \sim N(1,2)$$ 
and $$P(X=X_1)=P(X=X_2)=\tfrac{1}{2}$$

which I have awkwardly expressed as

```
X2 = TransformedDistribution[
  2 T + 3 W, {W \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[3, Sqrt[5]], 
   T \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1, Sqrt[2]]}]

X1 = TransformedDistribution[
  T + W, {W \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[3, Sqrt[5]], 
   T \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1, Sqrt[2]]}]

XX = TransformedDistribution[
  i a + (1 - i) b, {a \[Distributed] X1, b \[Distributed] X2, 
   i \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[0.5]}]
```

This serves fine for generating `RandomVariate`s and for calculating `Mean`, `Variance`, etc.; but I would like to plot the PDF of $T$ vs $X$ and am struggling with how to correctly construct the joint PDF to do this.

How should I go about constructing these distributions so that the joint PDF, $f_{X,T}(x,t)$, can be plotted using, for example with `ContourPlot` or `Plot3D`?

Comment: I don't know how probability distributions work in Mathematica. Does Mathematica know that the `T` and `W` in the definitions of `X1` and `X2` are the same? Otherwise you won't get the right correlations. For example, consider `y = TransformedDistribution[x, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]; z = TransformedDistribution[x, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]`; are `y` and `z` independent?

Comment: @RahulNarain: Does that matter here, where I'm just looking at $X$, which is *either* $X_1$ or $X_2$?

Comment: Hmm... probably not, you're right.

Comment: @RahulNarain: Good catch though, for the general case (`i` not limited to $\{0, 1\}$).

Answer (score 2):

As a warm up, let's find the PDF of `XX`. Now if we just do `PDF[XX, x]`, *Mathematica* will seemingly spin forever, which one might think is caused by `Integrate`. Let's see if that's correct.

First let's `Print` each time we `Integrate`:

```
Block[{Integrate},
  Integrate[e__] /; (Print[{e}]; False) := Null;
  PDF[XX, x]
]
```

[image]

Ok so there is one integral, and notice we can simplify it by realizing `x3` is either `0` or `1` as seen in the `Assumptions` option above. Making our own custom integrator for this case we get an answer for the PDF of `XX`:

```
With[{X = \[FormalX]3},
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Integrate},
    Unprotect[Integrate];
    Integrate[e__] /; !FreeQ[{e}, X] := 
      Piecewise[{{Integrate @@ ({e} /. X->0), X==0}, {Integrate @@ ({e} /. X->1), X==1}}];

    PDF[XX, x]
  ]
]
(* 0.0273995 E^(-(1/106) (-11+x)^2)+0.075393 E^(-(1/14) (-4+x)^2) *)

Plot[0.0273995 E^(-(1/106) (-11+x)^2)+0.075393 E^(-(1/14) (-4+x)^2), {x, -10, 30}]
```

[image]

Now I'm a little fuzzy on how to compute a joint PDF but perhaps it can be computed in a similar fashion. (Let me know if this is the wrong way to find the joint pdf!):

```
With[{X=\[FormalX]3},
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Integrate},
    Unprotect[Integrate];
    Integrate[e__] /; !FreeQ[{e}, X] := 
      Piecewise[{{Integrate @@ ({e} /. X->0), X==0}, {Integrate @@ ({e} /. X->1), X==1}}];

    jcdf = Probability[
      X <= x && T <= t, 
      {X\[Distributed]XX, T\[Distributed]NormalDistribution[1,Sqrt[2]]}
    ];

    jpdf = D[jcdf, x, t]
  ]
]
(* 0.0705237 E^(-0.25 (-1.+t)^2) (0.109598 E^(-0.00943396 (-11.+x)^2)+0.301572 E^(-0.0714286 (-4.+x)^2)) *)

Plot3D[jpdf, {x, -10, 30}, {t, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, AxesLabel -> {x, t}]
```

[image]

### Edit:

I feel this is wrong because `Probability` thinks `X` and `T` are independent... and I'm pretty sure they're dependent, is that correct?

Comment: My *Mathematica* formulation may not be the correct way to capture the mathematical formulation (which is definitive) at the start of the question. It works for some applications (see my comment) but not generally, and perhaps not here.